# Dereferencing Pointer Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dereference

I have a problem in this code segment
`printf("\nIn Func: %s", (*article[ctr]).artname);`

I use Code:Blocks and get the error "undefined reference to WinMain@16", article is a pointer array shouldn't I access it just by dereferencing it? I also tried with -> but without success.

May I disobey something?

Thanks for help, I added the complete code below.

Header-File:

```
#ifndef _LAGER_H
#define _LAGER_H

#define MAXCHAR 40

#define lagerdateiname "lager.dat"


struct artikel_t
{
  int artnr;
  char artname[MAXCHAR];
  float preis;
  int bestand;
  int min;
};

#endif
```

Code-File:

```
#include "lagdat.h"
#include <string.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int bestellMenge(struct artikel_t *article[], int len)
{
    int errCode;
    int retVal;
    int ctr = 0;
    struct artikel_t art;

    unsigned int writtenArticles = 0;
    unsigned int leftArticles = 0;

    errCode = openLager();



    if(!errCode)
    {
        int readOK;

        while(!(readOK = readNext(&art)) && ctr < len)
        {
            if(art.bestand < art.min)
            {
                article[ctr] = &art;
                ctr++;
                writtenArticles++;


                printf("\nIn Func: %s", (*article[ctr]).artname);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where is your main() function?

Comment: It's a Lib-File but thanks, restarting the IDE worked -.-' I only opend the C-File not the project, therefore Code:Blocks recognized it not as Library...

Comment: Indeed the solution to *this* problem is simple, however you've got a *far more* pressing problem, namely you're storing a pointer to the local variable `art`, which means that you'd get a crash when using the array of articles outside this function. You must use dynamic memory allocation with malloc here, or possibly have the readNext return a pointer to next article, NULL on error.

Comment: As for the `WinMain` error, it has nothing to do with this code here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to print before ctr++ as below. Currently you are trying to point an article object what you did not fill it

```
            article[ctr] = &art;
            printf("\nIn Func: %s", (*article[ctr]).artname);

            ctr++;
            writtenArticles++;
```